# ios 9 UIPopoverPresentationController constant placement on rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

in iOS9 when I rotate my screen with a UIPopoverPresentationController the coordinates are reset to 0 and not attached to my sourceView which is a button.

I have tried:

func popoverPresentationController(popoverPresentationController: UIPopoverPresentationController, willRepositionPopoverToRect rect: UnsafeMutablePointer, inView view: AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer) {
    rect.initialize(CGRectMake(200, 200, 400, 400))
}

but no avail.  Any help ?

Comment: `rect.initialize(CGRectMake(200, 200, 400, 400)` Really? If that's your code, no wonder nothing is happening.

Answer (score 2):

You could apply constraints to you sourceView button, then just use it as the popover source:

`myPopoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = button`

You also can set sourceView in the storyboard, but sourceRect needs to be set in code:

`myPopoverViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = button.bounds`

You need the correct source rect for the popover arrow to align properly.
Now you don't need to dismiss and present the popover on rotation. UIPopoverPresentationController does that for you. You don't even need to update sourceView/sourceRect once they are set on creating the popover.

Use `viewWillTransition` to catch size and orientation changes:

> ```
> override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
>     super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
>     coordinator.animate(alongsideTransition: { _ in
>         if self.popover != nil {
>             // optionally scroll to popover source rect, if inside scroll view
>             let rect = ...
>             self.scrollView.scrollRectToVisible(rect, animated: false)
>
>             // update source rect constraints
>             buttonConstraint.constant = ...
>             button.setNeedsLayout()
>             button.layoutIfNeeded()
>         }
>     }, completion: nil)
> }
> ```

**Explanation:**
The trick with `animate(alongsideTransition: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)?, completion: ((UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext) -> Void)? = nil)` is that you should update your constraints in `alongsideTransition` closure, not in `completion`. This way you ensure that UIPopoverPresentationController has the updated sourceRect when restoring the popover at the end of rotation.

What might seem counter-intuitive is that inside `alongsideTransition` closure you already have your new layout that you derive your constraints calculation from.