# Xamarin.iOS Popovers on Rotate

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, popover

I've seen lots and lots of posts about handling rotation for iOS popovers, but the majority of them target < iOS8 and/or Swift/ObjC. How can I do this with `UIPopoverPresentationController` and Xamarin.iOS? I need to keep it in the center of the screen.

```
  public override void ViewDidLoad()
  {
     ...

     _menuController.PopoverPresentationController.PermittedArrowDirections = 0;
     _menuController.PopoverPresentationController.WillReposition += OnWillReposition;
  }

  private void OnMenuSelected(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
  {
     InitializePopover();

     PresentViewController(_menuController, true, null);
  }

  private void OnWillReposition(object sender, UIPopoverPresentationControllerRepositionEventArgs args)
  {
     InitializePopover();
  }

  private void InitializePopover()
  {
     _menuController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceRect = GetCenterRect();
     _menuController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = View;
  }

  private CGRect GetCenterRect()
  {
     var midX = View.Bounds.GetMidX();
     var midY = View.Bounds.GetMidY();
     return new CGRect(midX, midY, 0, 0);
  }
```

`OnWillReposition` is called on rotation, but setting the `SourceRect` and `SourceView` doesn't appear to take effect. When I rotate again, I can see during debug that those properties have the old values.

Popular links I've seen so far:

- [seems like it should work but doesn't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26280330/1964319) (am I listening to the
  wrong event?)
- [got the initial display working!](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31854391/1964319) but doesn't recenter
- [potential solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40065066/1964319) but what would I constrain?

Other thoughts:

- Can I reposition in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`? How?
- Using a `UIBarButtonItem` isn't really an option, but maybe an invisible one?
- Should I dismiss and present again? Seems hacky and I was getting exceptions...
- Should I give up and simply set another view over everything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out just before posting. My problem was that I wasn't setting `PermittedArrowDirections` each time. Vent: Who thought that was a good idea? Anyway, after making that part of initialization, I simply call that in `ViewDidLayoutSubviews`, as below:

```
  public override void ViewDidLayoutSubviews()
  {
     base.ViewDidLayoutSubviews();

     InitializePopover();
  }

  private void InitializePopover()
  {
     _menuController.PopoverPresentationController.PermittedArrowDirections = 0;
     _menuController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceRect = GetCenterRect();
     _menuController.PopoverPresentationController.SourceView = View;
  }
```

So I don't use the `UIPopoverPresentationController.WillReposition` event at all. I hope this helps somebody -- I wouldn't want my worst enemy to go through all that frustration.